# Broken symlinks with snap installed packages in KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, symlink, kde-plasma, brave, snap

The example below  occurs with the Brave snap, but I think it also happens with all the other snaps.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Install Brave snap via Discover
2. Open Brave and add pin to Task manager
3. Update Brave (When available)

**Observed Result**

Clicking on the pinned icon throws this:

```
Plasma workspace error: 
The file or folder /snap/brave/**158**/opt/brave.com/brave/brave does not exist.
```

i.e., pinned icon doesn't work (app launching still works via app launcher)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THTVX.png)

**Expected Result**

App should open.

**Temporary Workaround**

Manually changing the symlink from "/snap/brave/158/opt/brave.com/brave/brave " to "/snap/brave/**current**/opt/brave.com/brave/brave" works **BUT** updating the app recreates the problem : app doesn't open and

```
Plasma workspace (updated) error : 
The file or folder /snap/brave/**160**/opt/brave.com/brave/brave does not exist.
```

**Software/OS version**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System Distribution | KDE neon 5.24 |
| KDE Plasma Version | 5.24.5 |
| KDE Frameworks Version | 5.93.0 |
| Qt Version | 5.15.3 |
| Kernel Version | 5.13.0-41-generic (64-bit) |
| Graphics Platform | X11 |
| Processors | 4 × Intel® Core™ m3-6Y30 CPU @ 0.90GHz |
| Memory | 3.6 GiB of RAM |
| Graphics Processor | Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 515 |

**Additional information**

I have noticed the version number in the path name (here:160) differs from the the new version numbers, after the update.
My current folders are :

```
/snap/brave/162
/snap/brave/161
/snap/brave/current
```